# Populate Expandable Listview from mysql crashes app

Tags: android, expandablelistview, baseadapter

I am trying to populate an expandable listview from the database and the app crashes without any log

My code:

The onCreateView:

```
    private View rootView;
    private ExpandableListView lv;
    private BaseExpandableListAdapter adapter;
    private String jsonResult;
    private String url = "http://reservations.cretantaxiservices.gr/files/getspirits.php";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<ProductList> childs;
    String[] products;
    ArrayList<ExpandableListParent> customList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_spirits_fragment, container, false);
        lv = (ExpandableListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spiritsListView);
        final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isAvailable() && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (!network_connected) {
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        } else {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                accessWebService();
                registerCallClickBack();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        accessWebService();
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

The JSONTask

```
public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, ArrayList<ExpandableListParent>> {
        public JsonReadTask() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_stocks));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ExpandableListParent> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                customList = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("spirits");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("type");
                    String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                    String image = jsonChildNode.optString("image");

                    String p1 = jsonChildNode.optString("product1");
                    String p2 = jsonChildNode.optString("product2");
                    String p3 = jsonChildNode.optString("product3");


                    products = new String[]{p1, p2, p3};

                    childs.add(new ProductList(price, products, image));

                    customList.add(new ExpandableListParent(name, childs));
                }
                return customList;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ExpandableListParent> customList) {
            if(customList == null){
                Log.d("ERORR", "No result to show.");
                return;
            }
            ListDrawer(customList);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }

    public void ListDrawer(ArrayList<ExpandableListParent> customList) {
        adapter = new ExpandListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), customList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ExpandableListParent> groups;


    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExpandableListParent> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).getChilds().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition).getChilds().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpandableListParent group = (ExpandableListParent) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_item_parent, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_text);
        tv.setText(group.getName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ProductList child = (ProductList) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name_coffee);
        tv.setText(child.getName());
        TextView tvp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_price_coffee);
        tvp.setText("5");
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_image_coffee);
        Ion.with(iv).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).load(child.getImage());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at fragments.SpiritsFragment$JsonReadTask.doInBackground(SpiritsFragment.java:225)
        at fragments.SpiritsFragment$JsonReadTask.doInBackground(SpiritsFragment.java:161)
```

The error lines:

```
SpiritsFragment.java 225: childs.add(new ProductList(price, products, image));

SpiritsFragment.java 161: public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, ArrayList<ExpandableListParent>>
```

And when i open the app it just gets me back to the 1st activity without any logcat output for the reason this is happening.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `1st activity without any logcat output for the reason this is happening` log is not showing because you are not using `e.printStackTrace();` in catch block. use `e.printStackTrace();` in every catch block and post crash log with question

Comment: well i editted my question and you can see the error above now. It also says that i have error in `SpiritFragment.java` where this line is `pDialog.show();` any ideas?

Comment: Is `NewOrder` is your class? show more log because issue is in `NewOrder` class

Comment: You tagged this with 'mysql'; please show us the relevant SQL code.  (Or remove the tag.)

Comment: @KostasDrakonakis The logged error is simply because you're calling `getActivity().finish();` without having dismissed the dialog (hence, a _window leak_ as stated). But this is actually only a side effect of a previous exception. In the `catch` block, you should log the exception (i.e. `e.printStackTrace()` so you can diagnose the real problem).

Comment: so what is your suggerstion?

Comment: remove } catch (Exception e) { to better see the error

Comment: it didnt worked either

Comment: Your ArrayList<ProductList> childs is initialized?

Comment: It's pretty clear that your childs list isn't initialized before you try to add items to it in the AsyncTask.

Comment: the thing is that it shows the expandable listview but it does not show the right products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your onCreateView initialize the arraylist first as

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    childs = new ArrayList<ProductList>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your `inputStreamToString` method in your AsyncTask.

In the `catch` in this method, you should either throw the exception again so that `doInBackground`, the calling method, can handle it (and therefore print the stack trace)... or handle in it some way within `inputStreamToString`.

Since you are calling `getActivity().finish()` here, the activity is ending before anything can be logged at all.

For example:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
}
```